# Two Images on one Object in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, textures

I have two textures. One is jpg and the other is png. I have rendered a cube and I want to use the jpg image as a background in every face of the cube and then have the png on this background. I tried `mix()` but i can see the background through png and I don't want that. Is there any function that can do this for me?

Fragment Shader:

```
#version 330 core

struct Light {
    vec3 direction;
    vec3 ambient;
    vec3 diffuse;
    vec3 specular;
};

struct Material {
    float shininess;
};

out vec4 FragColor;

in vec3 FragPos;
in vec3 Normal;
in vec2 TexCoords;

uniform vec3 viewPos;
uniform sampler2D texture1;
uniform sampler2D texture2;
uniform Light light;
uniform Material material;

void main() {
    
    // ambient
    vec3 ambient = light.ambient * mix(texture(texture1, TexCoords), texture(texture2, TexCoords), 0.0).rgb;

    // diffuse 
    vec3 norm = normalize(Normal);
    vec3 lightDir = normalize(-light.direction);  
    float diff = max(dot(norm, lightDir), 0.0);
    vec3 diffuse = light.diffuse * diff * mix(texture(texture1, TexCoords), texture(texture2, TexCoords), 0.0).rgb;  

    // specular
    vec3 viewDir = normalize(viewPos - FragPos);
    vec3 reflectDir = reflect(-lightDir, norm);  
    float spec = pow(max(dot(viewDir, reflectDir), 0.0), material.shininess);
    vec3 specular = light.specular * spec * mix(texture(texture1, TexCoords), texture(texture2, TexCoords), 0.0).rgb;  
        
    vec3 result = ambient + diffuse + specular;
    FragColor = vec4(result, 1.0);

}
```

`texture1` is the png and `texture2` is the jpg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mix the color depending on the alpha channel of the PNG texture. Assuming texture1 is the JPG and texture2 is the PNG, [`mix`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/mix.xhtml) `texture1` and `texture2` depending on `texture2`'s alpha channel:

```c
vec4 color_jpg = texture(texture1, TexCoords);
vec4 color_png = texture(texture2, TexCoords);
vec3 color = mix(color_jpg.rgb, color_png.rgb, color_png.a);
```

---

Fragment shader:

```c
void main()
{
    vec4 color_jpg = texture(texture1, TexCoords);
    vec4 color_png = texture(texture2, TexCoords);
    vec3 color = mix(color_jpg.rgb, color_png.rgb, color_png.a);

    // ambient
    vec3 ambient = light.ambient * color;

    // diffuse 
    vec3 norm = normalize(Normal);
    vec3 lightDir = normalize(-light.direction);  
    float diff = max(dot(norm, lightDir), 0.0);
    vec3 diffuse = light.diffuse * diff * color;  

    // specular
    vec3 viewDir = normalize(viewPos - FragPos);
    vec3 reflectDir = reflect(-lightDir, norm);  
    float spec = pow(max(dot(viewDir, reflectDir), 0.0), material.shininess);
    vec3 specular = light.specular * spec * color;  
        
    vec3 result = ambient + diffuse + specular;
    FragColor = vec4(result, 1.0);
}
```